# Sending a friend an xCode project/Sharing an xCode project

Tags: xcode, bundle, nib, sharing

I am currently trying to share an xCode project with a friend and I want to know the easiest way to share the project with him. The main reason that I want to share it with him is, because I want to run it in class, but I have a desktop. He currently is getting the error message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''

I really want to be able to run the application on the ios simulator for class, so if there is an easier way of just grabbing the application or some other way to present the application.

Comment: Path error. Use relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: For some reason that still seems to do nothing. I changed from relative to group to relative to project and that seems to not change anything either.